# SharedPreferences file

Tags: android

Does somebody knows where the file with the actual stored SharedPreferences is located?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes I know.

```
/data/data/com.your.package/shared_prefs/com.your.package_preferences.xml
```

So you get there by running in console:

```
# adb shell
# cd /data/data/com.your.package/shared_prefs/
# ls
```

Comment: The filename may vary, depending on how the `SharedPreferences` were constructed, but the directory is correct.

Comment: If i want to see the Data that are stored in to that XML file then  ? Please reply on this as i realy need it. . .

Comment: To stay at the example here: `cat com.your.package_preferences.xml`  But you have to have a rooted phone to be able to read.

Comment: any chance to access that on a non rooted phone ?

Comment: No, you need to root it to circumvent the user based access system, every application has an unique user.
If the application in question made the preference-file world-readable, this does not apply and you should be able to cat/read it.

Comment: @njzk2: You don't need to root your phone, you can just use the `run-as` utility, e.g. `adb shell run-as com.your.package cat /data/data/com.your.package/shared_prefs/com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses_preferences.xml`

Comment: This answer is outdated already for Android 6. E.g. on my device shared preferences are located inside /data/user/0/...

Correct way to find location of the shared preferences folder is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14651771/297710

File prefsdir = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir,"shared_prefs");
...