# Why the toogleButton get in its default mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

In my application there are two tabs like SettingTab And ApplicationTab.
Now in setting tab i have toogleButton. I am storing the tooglebutton selection in sharedpreference with this code:

```
myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

    toogleForFullResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (((ToggleButton)v).isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Full Result Sound is On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("FullResultIsOn", true);
            }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Full Result Sound is Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               prefsEditor.putBoolean("FullResultIsOn", false);
           }

        }
    });
```

prefsEditor.commit();

And in ApplicationTab, based on the selection of the toogleButton i am playing some sound. The code is like:

```
myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    fullResultSound = myPrefs.getBoolean("FullResultIsOn", false);
    lessResultSound = myPrefs.getBoolean("LessResultIsOn", false);

 if(fullResultSound)
    {
        SettingsTab.toogleForFullResult.isChecked();

    }

if(fullResultSound)
        {
            playSound(soundFileForFullResult);
        }
        else
        {
            playSound();
        }
```

Now the problem is, if i select the toogleon then it wirks only for once. And thne if i again start the activity, then the toggle is off. Why i am not able to store the toogle selection in to the sharedPreference ?
Please help me.. Thanks.

Comment: might need to make it writable. myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE);

Comment: @blessenm i have edited Mode from MODE_WORLD_READABLE to MOCE_WORD_WRITABLE but still it not works. Still the toggle button remain in its default "off" condition even if i have selected it as "on".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566430/sharedpreferences-file this tells about the location of the shared preference file. Try acessing it and see if you values are actually getting stored in the file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the link. Let me check it.,

Comment: I got that xml file based on the given instruction. but i am not able to see the data in to that file. So now how can i able to see that data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the

```
prefsEditor.commit();
```

inside the onclick listener so that the changes are saved. Right now it is outside.

Comment: Ok. I have keep it in to the listener. but still when i close the application or start the another activity in to that application and after wen i see that toogleButton, the state of the button remains as default. Not as we have changed. So what more i nedd to do ?

Comment: your code is working for me. You might need to debug on your own by pulling the preference file after each operation to see if you're accidentally doing something.