# SharedPreferences xml file

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

In Eclipse (DDMS) I have folder shared_prefs, where located my SharedPreferences files.  Can I open this files from Eclipse for view content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes

```
/data/data/com.your.package/shared_prefs/com.your.package_preferences.xml
```

So you get there by running in console:

```
# adb shell
# cd /data/data/com.your.package/shared_prefs/
# ls
```

taken from here: [SharedPreferences file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566430/sharedpreferences-file)

Comment: Thank you. How can I open console?

Comment: Sorry, but I get "NameFile.xml". How can I view key-value payirs?

Comment: do an adb pull and view the file locally