# Where are Shared Preferences saved on Nexus S?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharedPreferences file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566430/sharedpreferences-file)

Where are the shared preferences saved on a Nexus S?  I have an app that creates and uses shared preferences and need to gain access to the preferences from outside the app - like with a file explorer. Before you answer with the location of some xml file, I listed every xml file on my device and there are none that are named preferences or with any name that looks like it could be for a preferences file.

Answer (score 2):

You can only access SharedPreferences outside your app if the device is rooted. They are located at:

```
/data/data/#packageName#/shared_prefs/#filename#.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your phone is rooted you cannot get the shared Preferences of a particular app.

If it is rooted you can get it at

```
/data/data/[yourpackagename]/
```