# Android: how to get list of all preference xml's for my app and read them?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, readfile, android-file

how to get list of all application preferences for application,

**1.** I am saving shared preference in this manner[image: Activity to save key value pair in desired preference xml]

**2.** I know that they are in `data/data/app_packagename/shared_prefs`
[image: Preference Xml's shared_pref folder]

---

**3. THE PROBLEM:** But how to get list of all preference xml files in a spinner 
[image]

and read each preference, i searched in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com), but i did not found any help regarding this, how to do read all preference xml files in my application directory and access the preferences?

***P.S:*** I am aware of `SharedPreference.getAll();`, will be enough to read once i get the file?

I have wrote in bits(Rough Code), it give error when tried to run, here is the implemented method

```
void getList()
{
  //will be invoked from onCreate to populate spinner,yes spinner is already binded
   PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
        String s = getPackageName();
        try {
            PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
            s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("yourtag", "Error Package name not found ", e);
        }
        Log.i("dir", s=s+"/shared_prefs");
     //is this write way, how to proceed from here
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this

```
    File prefsdir = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir,"shared_prefs");

    if(prefsdir.exists() && prefsdir.isDirectory()){
        String[] list = prefsdir.list();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,list);
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

//To get the selected item

```
String item = (String) sp.getSelectedItem();
    //remove .xml from the file name
    String preffile = item.substring(0, item.length()-4);

    SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences(preffile, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> map = sp2.getAll();          

    for (Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("key is "+ entry.getKey() + " and value is " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Is "shared_prefs" guaranteed to be always the name of the directory containing the shared preferences files?

Comment: @Androrider It is not part of the public api, so it is not guaranteed to be the same in future releases, but all the previous releases have this folder

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use reflection, there is an @hide function Context#getSharedPrefsFile(String name)

So you would call

Context#getSharedPrefsFile(String name).getParentFile() to get a reference to the shared_prefs dir

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // load the XML preferences file
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Then in your main class, you can refer to the preferences

```
public class DrinkingBuddy extends Activity 
                           implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private int weight;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // register preference change listener
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // and set remembered preferences
        weight = Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weightPref", "120");
        // etc
    }

    // handle updates to preferences
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        if (key.equals("weightValues")) {
            weight = Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weightPref", "120");
        }
        // etc
    }
}
```

The saving of preference updates is handled for you.

(Not too sure about public/private declarations!).

Comment: in no way it answers my question