# Is it possible to get a shared preferences object when only a portion of the name is known?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Note this question is NOT about obtaining the contents of a SharedPreferences object if the keys are not known, it is about if its possible to obtain the SharedPreferences themselves if its name is not known.

Suppose there are SharedPrefreferences collections with 'file names' "something-a", "something-b", "something-c". Then is it possible to determine that there are 3 sets of SharedPreferences object available and to be able to get them when only the "something-" part of their name is known?

I guess not but hopefully there is.

I'm not going into the reasons behind the requirement except to say there is a requirement to update an app to Marshmallows permissions model and it needs to be capable of reading preferences files written by older versions of the app where the preferences name is "something-imsi". If the user has not granted the relevant permission on Marshmallow then the app does not know the imsi and thus I am trying to find out if its possible for the app to read the shared preferences when it doesn't know the full name.

Comment: I think this will do what I was looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580085/android-how-to-get-list-of-all-preference-xmls-for-my-app-and-read-them

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all preferences with `SharedPreferences.getAll()` and iterate over this collection for string keys that match your pattern. For example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
Map<String, ?> pairs = prefs.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : pairs.entrySet()) {
    // Check for your string pattern here...
}
```

This answer assumes you have one shared preferences file with keys matching the pattern described in the question. If that's not the case, and you have multiple dynamically named shared preferences files matching the pattern, it's a harder problem. You might make some progress by iterating over the files in `Context.getFilesDir()`

Comment: OP asked if he can figure out the no of different files of preferences present.

Comment: Thanks but the question isn't how to get the contents of a SharedPeferences object, its how to get that object in the first place if its name isn't known.

Comment: I see that now. As the edited answer says, that's a harder problem. If you are really motivated to solve the problem, see the source for Context.java: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java Although the `getSharedPrefsFile` method it contains is hidden, it can be accessed using Java reflection, and you go from there...

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get the list of file names of the preferences available. Though if you know the file name and then you can get an instance of the `SharedPreferences` and use `getAll` method to get all the keys present in that set of preferences.

Here is the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()

Example:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, 0);
    Map<String, ?> map = sharedPreferences.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> e : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        // this is the key that is present
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the question isn't how to get the contents of a SharedPeferences object, its how to get that object in the first place if its name isn't known.