# Is it possible to get Preferences file in actual device?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I save some data in user preferences in my app.
Is it possible to retrieve and read it from an actual device?
How can we retrieve?

Comment: yes Kissa Sy u can retrieve and read

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566430/sharedpreferences-file

Comment: @Kissa see the link i have posted that will help you

Comment: @GauravPandey yes, I already checked it. thank you so much. however, i got permission denied error. how can i be able to change permission so i can extract the file?

Comment: it's your application shared pref or others application

Comment: it's the application's shared pref.

Answer (score 3):

This Way You can get File at your Computer

[image]

Comment: If you got solution then close question by click on right question mark

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you do on the emulator

Comment: I tried but I don't know the exact location. Could you please help me with it? I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks for the quick answer by the way.